# Azure notification hubs - Windows (WNS) error - Invalid WNS credentials

Tags: azure, uwp, push-notification, azure-notificationhub, wns

I am trying to setup **Windows (WNS)** notifications based on following Microsoft tutorial: [Send notifications to Universal Windows Platform apps using Azure Notification Hubs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-windows-store-dotnet-get-started-wns-push-notification)

System returns error at *step 3* in chapter ***Configure WNS settings for the hub***. Relevant screenshots below.
I used fresh **Package SID** created yesterday. Also, **security key** was properly created; as defined in tutorial.

Error message:
`Error updating notification hub. Error. BadRequest. Message: **Invalid WNS credentials**.`

*App registration* in Azure is visible under - **Applications from personal account**.

On **Partner Center** portal I have active **individual developer**  account that was used to *register application* (MSIX or PWA app) and get **Package SID**.

Followed all steps in tutorial. Triple checked everything. No other errors received. Account that I used to go through the tutorial has **OWNER permissions** on Azure subscription where **Notification Hub** is located. Security and access rights shouldn't be the problem.

Any thoughts where is the problem? And where can I find more details about actual error?

[screenshot-ErrorMessage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnaLV.jpg)

[screenshot-App registration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqKhs.jpg)

[screenshot-IntegrationAssistantSuggestions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3SmJ.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

Found solution.

Package SID should be in the format: ms-app://S-x-xx-x-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx....

And not in the format S-x-xx-x-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.... (this is how it looks in partner center portal)

Resolved.

Comment: Oh man, you saved me. I kept getting this error and didn't have the `ms-app://` before the Package SID. A little help text on that screen from Microsoft would go a long way.  Thank you so much!